# Problem with backtrace during STM32 debugging

Tags: stm32, firmware, stack

I've been working with a STM32 nucleo board, model F446RE, and my application code only uses low level drivers, no HAL features are employed.

My compilation process has been created manually, with a custom Makefile and a linking script based on [this template](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/blob/master/Projects/STM32446E-Nucleo/Templates_LL/SW4STM32/NUCLEO-F446RE/STM32F446RETx_FLASH.ld).

The project is compiled successfully, but when I try to debug via gdb-multiarch, the code flow is strange. After the debug is started, it breaks automatically at function `LL_SetFlashLatency`, without any previous breakpoint being set.

`bt` command returns the following stack

[image]

The text before the stack pointer print is in portuguese, and it means: "It's not possible to access address 0x20020014"
The sp value is also displayed, 0x2001ffd0.
Just by curiosity, I checked the sp value at frame 1, and it is 0x2001fff0.

What I understood is that the sp decreases its value by eight, due to the alignment settings defined at the linking script, each time a new content is pushed to the stack. Therefore, the previous value in bt should be 0x2001ffd8, if none parameter is passed.

My questions are:

1. Why does my code stop at LL_SetFlashLatency without any breakpoint set?
2. Why does the bt stops at frame 1? It should display the whole calling history.
3. In the linking script, the stack end address is defined as 0x20020000. However, gdb complains about  0x20020014 not begin accessible. It seems to me that the stack pointer is being set to a value beyond 0x20020000, and it shouldn't be possible, because the RAM memory ends at 0x20020000. How can I check if the stack pointer is initiated at the wrong starting address?

Comment: Looks to me like your stack pointer got corrupted somehow. I assume that `latency` is a local variable in the function, so when the code tries to access it, it's going to be looking somewhere on the stack (in this case at sp + 0x44). Since your STM32F446 doesn't have any memory at that address, it generates a HardFault (probably actually a MemManage Fault which gets redirected to HardFault).

Comment: Since the stack in C starts at the top and works down, I would expect the 'function entry' code at the start of this function to automatically adjust the sp by however much it needs to cater for the local variables in the function - in this case at least 0x44 bytes- so at the start of the function, sp should be at 0x2001FFBC or lower. So either that doesn't happen for some reason, or some other code is modifying sp inappropriately.

Comment: I have completly different idea. `LL_SetFlashLatency` name indicates that you are reconfiguring Flash memory at the time of crash. Do you configure FLASH memory properly? If not, nothing is garuantue. In the worst case, when FLASH wait states (Latency) are not assures, MCU can execute completly different instructions.

Comment: I still don't know what's happening, but I noticed that the function address pointed by the dump code is different from what is shown by the gdb-multiarch.
In the dump, the address of my function "ConfigureWatchdogs" is 0x08000d30. However, when I set the breakpoint "b ConfigureWatchdogs", gdb returns 0x08000d34.

Comment: It is only 4 byte difference which may be caused by several reasons, but it is hard to estimate without knowing generated assembly. My guess is that at address 0x08000d30 compiler stored some 32-bit constant and actual executable code of the function begins at 0x08000d34. Function code later address the constant using relative addressing.